# Why won't this work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter, userscripts

I am using this userscript in both IE and FF and it works fine in both, however in Chrome nothing happens.
The script is supposed to count up new tweets posted to Tweetdeck, change the background color of those tweets and put the number of new ones in the tab title. Once your mouse has gone over the tweet it will decrease the number by 1 and change the color back. Code is below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     TweetDeck Unread Notifications
// @include  https://tweetdeck.twitter.com
// @include  https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var head, style;
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = ".tdUnreadUnread { background-color: #444444; }";
head.appendChild(style);

function animate_bg(ele, from, to) {
ele.css("background-color", "rgba(68, 68, 68, " + (from += from > to ? -1 :    1) / 10 + ")");
if(from != to)
    setTimeout(function() { animate_bg(ele, from, to)}, 20);
}

var counter = 0;
var loadingTime = true;

unsafeWindow.tdUnreadRefresh = function() {
var detail = $(".js-detail-content");
$("article").each(function(i) {
    if (detail.length === 0) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("tdUnreadUnread")) {
        $(this).addClass("tdUnreadUnread");
        if (!loadingTime) {
            counter++;
            $(this).mouseenter(function() {
                counter--;
                $(this).off("mouseenter");
                animate_bg($(this),10,0);
            });
        } else animate_bg($(this),10,0);
    }
    }
});
if (counter>0) {
    document.title = "("+counter+") TweetDeck";
} else {
    document.title = "TweetDeck";
}
};
unsafeWindow.tdUnreadLoadingOver = function() {
loadingTime = false;
};

setInterval("tdUnreadRefresh()",1000);
setTimeout("tdUnreadLoadingOver()",30000);
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
Bob

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console? Or does, literally, nothing happen?

Comment: He gets, for sure: `VM651:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: unsafeWindow is not defined(…)`.  What is the `unsafeWindow` variable you use in your script?